# Codeigniter set output directory for image lib

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to watermark an image. Is there a way to set a new folder for the output ?

According to documentation, it seems no : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#watermarking

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/image.jpg';`

Comment: I have tryed new_image, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the path you have given in `$config['new_image']`

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration array you and specify an 'upload_url'.

```
$config = array(
// Use "upload" library to select image, and image will store in root directory "uploads" folder.
'upload_path' => "uploads/",
'upload_url' => base_url() . "uploads/",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf"
);
```

I pulled that code from this tutorial: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-image-library/

Comment: This is for an upload of an image, not image lib.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I assume that you upload an image, manipulate it with image library and then save it with the file library?